# Create dynamic divs based on conditional statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dynamic div based on a button click only if that div has not been created before. For example, if div one does not exist, create div one. If only div one but not div two exists, create div two, etc. The problem that the program is adding more than one div at a time

```js
function createDivs() {
    if (document.getElementById('div0') === null) {
      divGenerator(1, 'div0', 'class1');
    }
    // Create Div 2
    if (document.getElementById('div0') !== null && document.getElementById(
      'div1') === null) {
      divGenerator(1, 'Div1', 'class2');
      
    } //create div 3
    if (document.getElementById('div0') !== null && document.getElementById(
      'div1') !== null && document.getElementById('div2') === null) {
      divGenerator(2, 'div2', 'class3');
    }
  }
  // dynamic div creator

function divGenerator(number_of_divs, divId, className) {
  var div, container, counter;
  container = document.getElementById('container');
  for (counter = 0; counter < number_of_divs; counter++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    //div.id = "div" + counter;
    div.id = divId;
    div.className = className;
    div.innerHTML = divId;
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/createDivs.js"></script>

  <title>Create Divs</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="createDivs();">Add Div</button>

  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls are executed in sequence, so it's checking for the existence of the divs it just finished creating. Reverse them so the last comes first.

Comment: I reversed the order of the conditional statements and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked for me, I did a couple things different like use a event listener for your button. On your second div... you had (Div1) instead of (div1) so the getElementById did not work. I've tried generating multiply divs and it work. Awesome idea by the way.

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function() {
    if (document.getElementById('div0') === null) {
      divGenerator(3, 'div0', 'class1');
    }

    else if (document.getElementById('div0') !== null && document.getElementById(
      'div1') === null) {
      divGenerator(3, 'div1', 'class2');
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('div0') !== null && document.getElementById(
      'div1') !== null && document.getElementById('div2') === null) {
      divGenerator(2, 'div2', 'class3');
    }
});


function divGenerator(number_of_divs, divId, className) {
  var div, container, counter;
  container = document.getElementById('container');
  for (counter = 0; counter < number_of_divs; counter++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    //div.id = "div" + counter;
    div.id = divId;
    div.className = className;
    div.innerHTML = divId;
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was was taking a shortcut with the inline onclick() function. But you are right to suggest the addEventListener() method which is the recommended way.

Comment: Your welcome! I do the same thing, make sure it works before I start cleaning my code up. @TomalSmith